# C# background worker to update status label

Tags: c#, winforms, label, backgroundworker

This should be a fairly simple thing; however, I've been unable to figure this out.

```
/// This section is located in the InitializeComponent() method
/// form's class, i.e. partial class frmMain { .... }
this.bgw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
this.bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
this.bgw.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.bgw_DoWork);
this.bgw.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.bgw_ProgressChanged);

/// This code is located in public partial class frmMain : Form { .... }
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); // Wait 100 milliseconds
        //Console.WriteLine(i);
        bgw.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update status label
    lblStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}
// New code added to question after edit
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    // some more stuff...
}
```

The background worker is running correctly; however, it is not correctly updating its progress. If I uncomment the commented line in the DoWork event, I able able to see the status updated correctly; however, the ProgressChanged event does not get triggered until after the task (heavy database computational stuff) in the main thread is finished.

This is using .NET Framework 4 and is a Windows Forms Application.

**Edit**

See the comments in the above code for where the code is located.

*Some more details*

The code that is being executed involves executing multiple queries on a database. I am not at liberty to disclose that code. As far as how that code is being executed, I actually do not know, as I was handed a .dll by another developer and was told to only use that when accessing the database....

**Edit**

The code in the "some more stuff" section was moved to be as follows

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // some more stuff... aka run queries!
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint in the `bgw_ProgressChanged` method to see if it is being called, and to see what the value in `e.ProgressPercentage` is?

Comment: I have just tested your code in a brand new solution and it works. Perhaps you should post a little more code, what is being done, etc. Based on your code, you never start background worker and the part of the code is not located within the function body, but within the class. The location of the code and how/when is it being called is very important in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: It is being called. The label updates to "3", then stops and updates again starting at about "85" or so. Adding `lblStatus.Update();` after setting the text appears to bring it up to an initial update of "5", but it still doesn't update while the database task is being executed.

Comment: Since it's unreproducible, you are calling `bgw.RunWorkerAsync();`  to start the code, correct?

Comment: I still can't repro. Longshot: Does it matter if you call `RunWorkerAsync` from `Form_Load` instead of the ctor?

Comment: your `//some more stuff` must be blocking the UI thread.  Make sure that whatever is there doesn't take long to run.

Comment: @Servy, you are probably right. This is where I originally had the database being updated, as it has to be updated before the program starts. I tried moving that bit of code to the form's Load event; however, this still did not fix it. Is there another place that would be appropriate?

Comment: @Slayer537 That needs to be done in a background thread, not the UI thread (formload is in the UI thread).  Really, it should be in the DoWork of the BGW.  That's the appropriate place for something like a database request.

Comment: @Servy I don't think you're right. Background worker runs on a completely different thread, so nothing from the main thread should be blocking it, right?

Comment: @NikolaMalešević That is correct, the BGW code here is fine.  The problem is that there is code that is not shown here which is running in the UI thread, and that is blocking all UI updates.  The code in the BGW is running just fine (which is why the console prints were working) but because another thread is blocking the UI, the UI updates still aren't being seen by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BackgroundWorker` code is just fine.  The problem is that you have code elsewhere (in this case, in your constructor or `FormLoad`) that is blocking the UI thread (by performing a synchronous database request).  You need to do something to ensure that this code is run in a non-UI thread.  This could mean using this existing `BackgroundWorker` to perform those other long running tasks; it could also be done by using `Task.Factory.StartNew` or some other threading mechanism to have it run in a non-UI thread.

Once the UI thread is not being blocked you will see the updates made in your `ProgressChanged event handler reflected in the UI.

Comment: I'll try to move the database intensive code into a different thread. Doing it really quick resulted in a bunch of cross-threading issues, so this will most likely be a non-trivial task. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Interesting. The obviously wrong answer was deleted, and then we both got downvoted...

Answer (score 2):

[@Servy is of course correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044899/11808)

I just wanted to chime in with this code that reproduces the problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeMoreStuff);
    }

    private void SomeMoreStuff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            this.Invoke((Action)HogTheUIThread);
        }
    }

    private void HogTheUIThread()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Wait 100 milliseconds
            //Console.WriteLine(i);
            bgw.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update status label
        lblStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
}
```